# SQL query with the BETWEEN-command, in CRAN R to select dates

Tags: sql, r, between, sqldf

The ff. example is taken from:
https://www.datenbanken-verstehen.de/sql-tutorial/sql-between-befehl/

Just started to learn **SQL** in R. I want to get a list of dates in between those two dates as set out in 'newdf.Mitarbeiter4'. Can anyone please help me pointing out the mistake in my query?
There are similar questions about this query, but somehow I still could not use the answers in identifying my mistake.

```
Mitarbeiter4 <- data.frame( Nachname = c( "Wegner", "Müller", "Schulz", "Richter", "Schröder" ),
                            Vorname = c( "Lutz", "Melanie", "Dorothea", "Heiko", "Lukas" ),
                            Geburtstag = c( '12.12.1983', '01.04.1978', '13.02.1990', '15.08.1995', '24.07.1980' )
                          )

Mitarbeiter4

newdf.Mitarbeiter4 <- sqldf( "SELECT Nachname, Vorname, Geburtstag from Mitarbeiter4 WHERE Geburtstag BETWEEN '1980.01.01' AND '1993.01.01' " )

newdf.Mitarbeiter4
```

which gives me the ff. result:

> [1] Nachname   Vorname    Geburtstag
>
> <0 Zeilen> (oder row.names mit Länge 0)

I tried for the dates both "." and "/" as in the other questions asked, but still no success on my side.

As I have problems with the correct formatting could I please refer the kind person who replies to my question to the result as in the tutorial quoted above under:

"Das Ergebnis würde wie folgt aussehen:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be better to convert to `Date` class and then do

```
library(sqldf)
Mitarbeiter4$Geburtstag <- as.Date(Mitarbeiter4$Geburtstag, "%d.%m.%Y")
start <- as.Date("1980-01-01")
end <- as.Date("1993-01-01")
fn$sqldf("SELECT Nachname, Vorname, Geburtstag from Mitarbeiter4 
           WHERE Geburtstag between $start and $end")
# Nachname  Vorname Geburtstag
#1   Wegner     Lutz 1983-12-12
#2   Schulz Dorothea 1990-02-13
#3 Schröder    Lukas 1980-07-24
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
Mitarbeiter4 %>% 
    filter(between(dmy(Geburtstag), as.Date("1980-01-01"), as.Date("1993-01-01")))
#   Nachname  Vorname Geburtstag
#1   Wegner     Lutz 12.12.1983
#2   Schulz Dorothea 13.02.1990
#3 Schröder    Lukas 24.07.1980
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
subset(Mitarbeiter4, as.Date(Geburtstag, "%d.%m.%Y") > as.Date("1980-01-01") & 
     as.Date(Geburtstag, "%d.%m.%Y") < as.Date("1993-01-01"))
#   Nachname  Vorname Geburtstag
#1   Wegner     Lutz 12.12.1983
#3   Schulz Dorothea 13.02.1990
#5 Schröder    Lukas 24.07.1980
```

NOTE: the `as.Date` conversion on the 'Geburtstag' column can be done before the filtering step in `subset` to avoid multiple calls to `as.Date`

Comment: continued: sorry I pressed RETURN,
well, yr first answer is great, it now works fine,
in another Tutorial I came across the "fn-sql" command, which motivates me now to work on it, because this BETWEEN command is highly necessary on a work which awaits me.